# Criar uma ISO no Docker sendo que não tem no hub.docker

Tags: docker

estou em dúvidas sobre o docker, pois já utilizo bem o vmware e o virtualbox,  neste caso queria instalar um Firewall o `OPNsense` e percebi que não tem um container preparado no docker e neste caso queria criar um mas não sei como o docker vai executar uma `ISO` para uma instalação normal do que é feito nos virtualizadores.

Comment: Já pensou em usar uma imagem do puppet e instalar isso com o puppet na criação do container?

Answer (score 2):

Como a imagem não existe, você vai precisar criá-la. Isso é feito com um arquivo chamado Dockerfile que tem mais ou menos essa estrutura:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
EXPOSE 80
VOLUME /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g forever
CMD forever -c node app.js
```

FROM é o nome da imagem base que você vai usar. Nesse caso eu uso a imagem básica do Ubuntu. EXPOSE indica uma porta que esse container irá escutar (como uma abertura de firewall). VOLUME é utilizado para compartilhar arquivos entre o container e a máquina host.

Nesse caso eu crio na estrutura de arquivos do meu container um diretório /src que poderá ser montado posteriormente pelo host. Funciona como as pastas compartilhadas do vmware, virtualbox.

WORKDIR nada mais é do que um comando cd que indica que todos os comandos executados pelo container devem ter o caminho /src como base. RUN serve para fazer com que o container execute um comando. Nesse caso eu instalo alguns pacotes.

Finalmente o CMD é um tipo especial de RUN que serve para dizer qual o propósito do container, ou seja, nesse caso o meu container tem como propósito rodar uma aplicação Node. Também é possível usar o ENTRYPOINT para isso, porém ele é mais utilizado para rodar serviços.

Após definido o Dockerfile, você precisa ir até o diretório onde ele está (usando cd) e rodar o comando docker build. Isso irá transformar seu Dockerfile em uma imagem pronta para ser executada com o docker run.

Como a imagem não existe no hub, você pode enviá-la para lá. Para isso você precisa criar uma conta no hub e na sua máquina rodar:

```
docker login
```

O comando irá pedir seu login e senha do hub. Finalmente você usa o comando abaixo para submeter sua imagem para o hub:

```
docker push seuusuario/suaimagem
```

Com isso, da próxima vez que você precisar dessa imagem, ao invés de ter que criar um Dockerfile e dar build, você pode simplesmente fazer:

```
docker run seuusuario/suaimagem
```

Referência do Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Sim é verdade mas o OPNsense ele é baseado no FreeBSD e o problema é que seu desenvolvimento feito em PHP ainda não está disponível um `make`; `make install`. Já ouvir falar que para instalar uma SO no `docker` você utiliza o `virtualbox` e exclui os arquivos de inicialização do kernel e exporta para montar. Existe dois exemplos sendo [CentOS #1](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/docker-user/TGvzjR4afzI) [CentOS #2](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/docker-user/HlPU1XIVw40) e o [Ubuntu](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/docker-user/TGvzjR4afzI/aIA-nQSZGq0J).